# Dynamically set the radius of a circle on AngularUI google maps

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, google-maps

As the title suggests I want to dynamically change the radius of the circle on my `ui-gmap-google-map` element, I've tried to use an onChange function on the textbox asking for a radius like so:

**The HTML**

```
<label for="distance" style="white-space: nowrap;">Enter a radius</label>
<input type="text" required class="form-control" placeholder="Kilometers" ng-change="setRadius()" name="distance" ng-model="map.marker.circle.radius" />
```

**In my Controller**

```
$scope.setRadius = function() {
    $scope.circles.radius = $scope.map.marker.circle.radius * 1000;
}
```

I also tried to directly change it in the "circles" array, but again, no result.

**The circles array**

```
$scope.circles = [
        {
            id: 1,
            center: {
                latitude: $scope.map.center.latitude,
                longitude: $scope.map.center.longitude
            },
            radius: $scope.circleRadius,
            stroke: {
                color: '#08B21F',
                weight: 2,
                opacity: 1
            },
            fill: {
                color: '#08B21F',
                opacity: 0.5
            },
            geodesic: true, // optional: defaults to false
            draggable: false, // optional: defaults to false
            clickable: false, // optional: defaults to true
            editable: false, // optional: defaults to false
            visible: true, // optional: defaults to true
            control: {}
        }
    ];
```

**The function to change radius**

```
$scope.setRadius = function() {
    $scope.circleRadius = $scope.map.marker.circle.radius * 1000;
}
```

**The HTML for the map**

```
<ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom">
<ui-gmap-window show="map.window.show" coords="map.window.model" options="map.window.options" closeclick="map.window.closeClick()">

</ui-gmap-window>

<ui-gmap-circle ng-repeat="c in circles track by c.id" center="c.center" stroke="c.stroke" fill="c.fill" radius="c.radius" visible="c.visible" geodesic="c.geodesic" editable="c.editable" draggable="c.draggable" clickable="c.clickable" control="c.control"></ui-gmap-circle>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have simply fixed this by setting the radius directly in the circles array (I don't feel like this is the best practise, but it works.

To clarify: When the distance gets changed I call the `setRadius()` function and simply set the radius by calling `$scope.circles[0].radius` which sets the radius.

**Nothing else needed**